# Systems of equations for elliptic curves without $3$-torsion

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, rational-points, magma

In his YouTube video [New rank records for elliptic curves having rational torsion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kxLBpj1Mzc), Noam Elkies uses systems of equations at 6:16 and 8:38 to present $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ curves of [rank 14](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Eduje/tors/z3old891011121314.html) and [rank 15](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Eduje/tors/z3.html).

I created a similar system of equations for a $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ curve of [rank 9](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Eduje/tors/z6.html) (edit: removed original infographic):
$$x+y+z=–73826006279$$
$$xyz=–13211438249850179974544071008000$$

I should have negated both equations, but it's too late now, as Andrej Dujella has already provided all the [integer solutions](https://twitter.com/dujella1/status/1473410623388241920).

Now I am trying to create a similar system for a curve without $3$-torsion, specifically for a $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ curve of rank 1 mentioned on p. 20 in our recently submitted paper

> Halbeisen, Hungerbuehler, Voznyy, and Zargar, *A geometric approach to elliptic curves with torsion groups $\mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Z/14\mathbb Z$, and $\mathbb Z/16\mathbb Z$*, [arXiv: 2106.06861](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.06861)

$$y^2 = x^3 + 10226878x^2 + 43046721x$$

> **Question $1$:** For the mentioned $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ curve, is it possible to keep a format similar to a $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ case (two equations, three variables, +, -, $\times$)? I would really like to avoid squaring/cubing the same variable.

> **Question $2$:** Is it possible to keep a similar format for any other curve having a $2$-torsion, but not $3$-torsion, i.e. for torsion subgroups $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: To make this self containd, could you explain what "fruit equations" are?

Comment: They are equations where variables are substituted by fruit emojis. Some recent examples: [link 1](https://thehighergeometer.wordpress.com/2021/07/27/diophantine-fruit/), [link 2](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-positive-integer-solutions-to-frac-x-y+z-+-frac-y-z+x-+-frac-z-x+y-4/answer/Alon-Amit), and [link 3](https://www.reddit.com/r/mathriddles/comments/gcunix/fruit_math_can_you_solve_it/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this system of equations satisfactory for Question 1:

$x+y+x \times z+y \times z=6400$,

$x \times y \times z=6561$?

It seems that all curves with torsion groups containing $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ can be obtained in this way. By taking $x+y+x \times z+y \times z= d$, $x \times y \times z=-cd$, we get the elliptic curve $[1,-c/d,-c/d,0,0]$ with a point $[0,0]$ of order $4$.

Comment: Following the suggestion in the answer, so far I was able to show that for the curves with torsion groups $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ and presented as $[0,a_2,0,a_4,0]$, it is possible to write $(x+y)(z+1)=2\sqrt{a_2+2\sqrt{a_4}}$ and $xyz=\sqrt{a_4}$. $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ don't follow suit yet.

Comment: For all curves with torsion groups containing $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, by comparing the $j$-invariants for $[0,a_2,0,a_4,0]$ and $[1,-c/d,-c/d,0,0]$, the possible values of $r=-c/d$ are obtained by solving the degree $6$ equation $\frac{-(1-16r+16r^2)^3}{r^4(-1+16r)}=\frac{256(a_2^2-3a_4)^3}{a_4^2(a_2^2-4a_4)}$. Then, for each torsion group, it is possible to write at least one system of equations $(x+y)(z+1)=d$, $xyz=-cd$.